# Sharepoint 2010 Ribbon Paste Command

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

currently SharePoint 2010 offers 2 ways to insert the clipboard content for example into a textfield. The normal paste which contains formatting and the "paste only text" option.

What I'd like to achieve is, that the "paste text only" option is the default and the other option is hidden. The user should have no chance to paste text with formattings in it.

What I've found so far is the RTE_OnPaste_Restricted Javascript function that does the trick but I can't find a way to set this as default for the ribbon. So I'm trying to hide the default paste button and replace it with my own but I don't know which command I should assign to this button. There is a lot more action around the paste command that happens, but I can't trace it with a Javascript debugger.

Looking closely on the javascript code you can see that the RichHtmlField Control from SharePoint comes with a restricted mode that would allow only text insert but to enable this mode you have to disable HTML Editing.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thx in Advance

Steve

Comment: With a little more investigation i found the function I was looking for: RTE.RichTextEditor.paste(true);

Comment: You could add that as answer to your question and then accept it, which will make it more useful for future readers of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little more investigation i found the function I was looking for: RTE.RichTextEditor.paste(true);